# What is default context for rendering in cytoscape.js lib?

Tags: canvas, graph, rendering, cytoscape.js

I know that cytoscape doesn`t support webgl-3d axes. But does it support webgl for rendering in 2D?

And what is the default context for rendering in cytoscape and if it`s canvas, how to use webgl in this case ?

For example I have to render 2k elements with edges from central element to all other elements using only 2d.

```
let layout = {
  container: document.getElementById('app'),
  elements: []
};

for(let i = 0, j = 2000, k = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
  layout.elements[i] = {
     data: { id: 'node_' + i }
  };
  layout.elements[j] = {
     data: {
        source: 'node_1000',
        target: 'node_' + k
     }
  };
     j++;
     k++
}

var cy = cytoscape(layout);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It uses `canvas2d` with plans to use a gl context to improve blitting performance in some instances.  But that doesn't really matter from a developer standpoint.  None of that is exposed to you by the API.